# Populate dropdown from one custom post type inside another custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, post-meta

[Solved -> see last comment in this question]

In custom post type CPT_A I am saving first_name and last_name via a custom metabox form field (they are not taxonomies):

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'first_name', esc_attr( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'last_name', esc_attr( $_POST['last_name'] ) )
```

In the database it looks like this:

```
post_id, meta_key, meta_value
186, first_name, John
186, last_name, Doe
323, first_name, Bill
323, last_name, Jones
```

In custom post type CPT_B I am trying to create a dropdown that is populated by CPT_A => first_name and last_name.

How do I loop through first and last name?

[Solved]
With help form Gareth Gillman' post I removed the foreach loop, moved the `<option>` into the while loop and changed get_the_id() to $query1->post->ID.

Here is the working solution. If there is a more eloquent way please comment.

```
<select name="mailing_name" id="mailing_name">

<?php 

$select_array = array();

$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'fooBar',
);

$query1 = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query1->have_posts() ) {

    $query1->the_post(); 

    $first_name = get_post_meta( $query1->post->ID, 'first_name', true);
    $last_name = get_post_meta( $query1->post->ID, 'last_name', true);

    echo '<option value="">' . $first_name . '&nbsp;' . $last_name . '</option>';

}

wp_reset_postdata();
?>

</select>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simple to add it elements to an option while you update post meta for CPT_A so that you could get the array from the updated option?

Comment: Not following you by adding an option. Either way don't you have to get an array from CPT_A? Where I am confused is do I need to get two arrays one for first and one for last name and then loop both as the <option>.

Comment: I was only saying that, for better performance not querying the database for PT data every time, when you "save first_name and last_name via a custom metabox" you would insert these data into an option which you use later. No need for 2 arrays, just one with Two-dimensional array. e.g `array( 186 => array( 'first_name' => 'John', 'last_name' => 'Doe' ), 323 => array( 'first_name' => 'Bill', 'last_name' => 'Jones' ) )`

Comment: Thats is a good idea, I will do that once I get a working dropdown. Tks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the db using wp_query to get all the posts from the CPT, save the metabox contents to an array and then print the array.

Not tested but should work (i hope):

```
<?php
$select_array = array();
$args = array (
 'post_type' => 'your_cpt',
);
$query1 = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
 $query1->the_post();
 $select_array[firstname] = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'the_meta_key', true);
$select_array[lastname] = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'the_meta_key', true);
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<select name="mailing_name" id="mailing_name">
 <?php
 foreach ($select_array as $option) {
  echo '<option value="">'.$option[firstname].'&nbsp;'.$option[lastname].'</option>';
 }
 ?>
</select>
```

Comment: That looks very promising, I will give it a try right now.

Comment: That worked, but I am only getting the first character, i.e., for John Doe it's J D.

Comment: wierd, i would print the meta field before it's added to the array to see if the meta key is correct before it's added.

Comment: Actually it's showing as J J and D D. The meta key is fine, but the $select_array is not right, see new comment in the question.

Comment: do a print_r($select_array); and show the results...... that will tell you if the array is fine...

Comment: I think the problem is get_the_id() it's should be the id found in $query1 [posts][0-4][id]. There are 5 results in $query1

Comment: get_the_id should get the individual post id for each post in $query1 so should be fine, but you could try $post->ID

Comment: Got it working, see the working code in my question. Gareth Gillman thanks for the help and if you see a better way please let me know.